# Appium - Connect Android to Docker Container

Tags: adb, appium-android

I'm trying to connect an Android device to a Docker container for Appium.  I was able to connect the device physically to my laptop, and then wirelessly to the laptop successfully.

However when I try `adb connect 10.2.3.156:5555` (the address of the device that worked for the laptop) in the container, and then do `adb devices` it says `10.2.3.156:5555 offline`.

I don't know how to physically connect the device to the container, or if that is something I would even want to do.  I would like it to connect wirelessly.

Have you encountered a problem like this and found any solutions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I think I figured this out.  When I did `adb connect 10.2.3.156:5555` from the container, I had to look on the Android and "Allow USB debugging".  However, I think I have a new issue now, where I need to automatically allow USB debugging from the device, because each container has a different RSA key fingerprint.